creating / signing a token using a private JWK encoded RSA key
im having problem creating a token using JWK private keys and from this snippet i get a {"error":"OpenSSL unable to validate key"}
when i try the key using packages in js/python i can seem to make it work however im just lost with the php implementation
ive read the documentation and tried wrapping / converting it to PEM but i still cant make it work
and i think its either im missing something or i should probably try my luck on a differnt package
any help would be appreciated since im already stuck with this for a while now
edit: ive managed to make it work after converting it to PEM (i did it in python though) is there a package in php that can do this? JWK->PEM?
tried using Jose\Component\Core\Util\RSAKey; but execution time > 30 seconds and im getting a timeout
use Jose\Component\Core\Util\RSAKey;

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
public static function createJwtToken()
{
    $jwkPrivateKey = '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';

    $privateKeyJson = json_decode(base64_decode($jwkPrivateKey), true);
    $jwk = new JWK($privateKeyJson);
    $pem = RSAKey::createFromJWK($jwk)->toPEM();

    // dd($privateKeyJson);

    if (! $privateKeyJson) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid private key format.');
    }

    $header = [
        'alg' => $privateKeyJson['alg'],
        'kid' => $privateKeyJson['kid'],
    ];

    $payload = [
        'sub' => 1,
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + 300, // Token expires in 5 minutes
    ];

    return JWT::encode($payload, $jwkPrivateKey, $header['alg'], $header['kid'], $header);
}



$jwkPrivateKey = <<<'EOD'
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;


The library seems to require a PEM key for RS256. ...and tried wrapping / converting it to PEM...: this is not found in your code.

youre right i left that out, ive updated the code snippet

Why are you using Firebase and the Web Token Framework libraries when one ir enough? Also, the execution time is slow because the extension GMP or BCMATH is required.

You do not use the generated PEM key at all. This must be passed as the second parameter in the JWT::encode() call, i.e. instead of $jwkPrivateKey. On my machine, the code works with this change.

yeah ive stated on the edit that i managed to make it work by using the PEM key. Apologies if i wasnt able to make it  clear. My problem now is how do i convert it to PEM key using php or some package, cause ive converted this using python and i dont want to handroll my own converter unless no choice

I cannot reproduce your performance problems, s. https://phpsandbox.io/n/moccasin-mon-mothma-acrao#index.php. This may be a problem specific to your environment.

Another PHP library for the JWK->PEM conversion is phpseclib. Also consider the 3rd comment, which suggests using one library instead of several. Why don't you use the web token framework for signing the token as well?

Topaco yeah i have problems when i try doing that, but as Spomky-Labs has mentioned i need to check on the required extensions which i wasnt aware of
